# sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php, sizeof

php7.2
помогите разобраться с sizeof

```
$mods = array('no_value' => $vbphrase['moderators']. ' (' . sizeof($cmodcache["$calendar[calendarid]"]) . ')');
if (is_array($cmodcache["$calendar[calendarid]"]))
{
    foreach ($cmodcache["$calendar[calendarid]"] AS $moderator)
    {
        $mods["$moderator[calendarmoderatorid]"] = "&nbsp; &nbsp; $moderator[username]";
    }
}
```

Comment: вам же говорят, что в sizeof надо дать массив или объект, который реализует Countable. А вы что ему суете?

Comment: Это так и было в php7.1, но в 7.2 не знаю как правильно дать массив или объект

Comment: А зачем вы везде в элементах используете кавычки? Да и проверка на наличие массива в элементе у вас ниже по коду, чем использование этого элемента как массива.

Answer (score -1):

Решил следующим способом:

> yii\base\ErrorException: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in G:\Server\data\htdocs\top-stm\www\vendor\masterexploder\phpthumb\src\PHPThumb\GD.php:972

Идем в этот файл и определяем закрытое свойство как массив

```
protected $options = [];
```

Comment: Разрешите полюбопытствовать: автор вопроса "motd2" и Вы - одно лицо? Если что, самоответы здесь вполне приветствуются!